Yolov8 fine-tuning but result still as pretrained
predict.py file
import cv2
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Load a pretrained YOLOv8 model
model = YOLO("best.pt") 

results = model.predict("output_IMG_7671.MOV", show=True)

When I finish my training with my customized data, then I tried to predict, but the result is still as pretrained outcome. But data.yaml file is actually within the new class, I need some help to deal with this problem.

Hello @user21569483 You can try this way
!yolo task=segment mode=predict model='/content/runs/segment/train/weights/best.pt'  source='/content/test.jpeg'   

//  yolo task=segment // segment or detect

